# Path to numerical algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

I try to self-study numerical algebraic geometry, and watch A J.Sommese's book 'The Numerical Solution of Systems of Polynomials', understanding this book need some background of algebraic geometry, such as complex analytic spaces, bertini theorem, but not need schemes and sheaves language which needed in modern algebraic geometry. I just want to learn this book and do not want to distract too far.

Right now, I have already self-studied funtional analysis,  John lee's book 'introduction to smooth manifolds', D.A Cox's book 'Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms' and right now, I study the book 'Algebraic Geometry A Problem Solving Approach' and 'visual Visual Complex Analysis'. Could someone recommended me some textbooks so I can have enough backgound to study numerical algebraic geometry? any other suggestions such as the order of studying or courses material is also welcomed.